# Make IDE/linter ignore a seemingly unused import

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

At my current work we have an enviroment py file contains the following imports:

```
from core.entities import * 
from core.entities.hdr import * 
from core.entities.scanner import *
```

However, all of these imports are seen as "unused" by the ide (Pycharm) and we sometimes experience someone making a commit where these have been removed by the IDE in the process. Is there a way to mark unused imports as not being unused?

Comment: Wildcard imports are not considered best practice in Python. There is a paragraph about them in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: I am well aware. It is however not the topic of my question, but thank you for bringing it to my attention

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try checking in the "Reformat File" dialog (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L), uncheck "Optimize imports", if already checked.

Alternatively, you can add `PyUnresolvedReferences':

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import A

# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import B
```

Although there are some reported issues with the reference, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19837 .

Comment: Okay, `PyUnresolvedReferences` may not work perfectly but it's better than nothing, at least for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `from core.entities import *  # noqa` that will do the same as `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences` in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `Unresolved references` inspections. you can turn it off by going:

```
Settings > Editor > General > Inspections > python
```

then you will see a checkbox in front of it.